# CKeditor Make inline editor readonly

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using inline editor of ckeditor for creating html content. How can i make it readonly and show only content for preview mode. I tried the following configuration but it is not working for me.

```
this.editorInstance.setReadOnly( true);
```

Here this.editorIntance is my editor. I want to show only content on preview mode and dont want to show toolbar of editor.

Answer (score 2):

Use following script to make the CKeditor read only. Pass 'true' or 'false' argument in `toggleReadOnly` function to make ckeditor disabled or enabled accordingly.

```
var editor;

// The instanceReady event is fired when an instance of CKEditor has finished
// its initialization.
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function ( ev ) {
    editor = ev.editor;

    // Show this "on" button.
    document.getElementById( 'readOnlyOn' ).style.display = '';

    // Event fired when the readOnly property changes.
    editor.on( 'readOnly', function () {
        document.getElementById( 'readOnlyOn' ).style.display = this.readOnly ? 'none' : '';
        document.getElementById( 'readOnlyOff' ).style.display = this.readOnly ? '' : 'none';
    } );
} );

function toggleReadOnly( isReadOnly ) {
    // Change the read-only state of the editor.
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setReadOnly
    editor.setReadOnly( isReadOnly );
}
```

Please refer working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/rbua57pq/3/

Comment: i tried this but it is not working in inline editor.

Comment: yes it is working. but your are using basic editor, Can you try with inline editor. link <div conteneditable="true" class="ckeditor"></div>

Comment: @GiteshPurbia Check my updated fiddle. I have used your <div conteneditable="true" class="ckeditor"></div> and it is working fine there

Comment: @GiteshPurbia Does it working? Have you checked new fiddle?

Comment: yes it is working. but i think i am working with angularjs. so i am binding content with ng-model. so i my case this is not working. i am providing content to ckeditor by ng-model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125106/discussion-between-rahul-patel-and-gitesh-purbia).